# How to populate list view data dynamically in senchatouch

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I wanted to populate the list data with below array variable i have set this arrray to store here is the list of records types inside the array

```
   var logbookEntryList = [];

  var aircraftMxLog = new AircraftMxLog(); //domian 

    aircraftMxLog.mxlogIdNum = mxLogIdNum;
    aircraftMxLog.entryDatetime = entryDatetime;
    aircraftMxLog.recordName = recordName;
    aircraftMxLog.recordSourceId = recordSourceId;

     logbookEntryList.push(aircraftMxLog);


   var mxRelease = new MxRelease();
   mxRelease.mxReleaseTypeId = mxReleaseTypeId;
    mxRelease.entryDatetime = entryDatetime;
    mxRelease.comments = comments;
    mxRelease.firstName = firstName;
    mxRelease.lastName = lastName;

     logbookEntryList.push(mxRelease);

    var flightLog = new FlightLog();
    flightLog.flightNumId = flightNumId;
    flightLog.arvStationId = arvStationId;
    flightLog.deptStationId = deptStationId;
    flightLog.outDate = outDate;
    flightLog.offDate = offDate;

    logbookEntryList.push(flightLog);
```

So like this i will be having different kinds of data in my array so how can i map this to my model to populate in list view

I have tried iterating the store through each function i was able to get each element object in iteration but am not able to set itemtpl while iterating dynamically to list

Here is the code

```
       createViewFactory :function(){
      var manageAmlStore=Ext.getStore('ManageAMLStore');
      manageAmlStore.setData(logbookEntryList);
     // this.getManageAmlStore().setData(logbookEntryList);
      //
        console.log('manage Aml store size '+manageAmlStore.getCount());
      var manageAmlList=Ext.getCmp('manageAMlList')
        manageAmlStore.each(function(item, index, length){
        //console.info(item,length,index);
        console.log('item '+item+' index '+index+' length '+length)
        console.log('item size '+item.length)
        if(logbookEntryList[index] instanceof AircraftMxLog){
            manageAmlList.setItemTpl('AircraftMxLog'+index);
         } else if(logbookEntryList[index] instanceof MxRelease){
            manageAmlList.setItemTpl('MxRelease'+index);
            // manageAmlList.initComponent();
              //manageAmlList.render();
         }else if(logbookEntryList[index] instanceof  FlightLog){
            manageAmlList.setItemTpl('FlightLog'+index);
          }else if(logbookEntryList[index] instanceof  MxAction){
            manageAmlList.setItemTpl('MxAction'+index);
         }
        //Ext.getCmp('manageAMlList').setItemTpl('test'+id)
         //this.getManageAmlList().setItemTpl('test'+id);
       });
      manageAmlList.bindStore(manageAmlStore);

     }
```

Comment: Did my answer helped you out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your system is that you are sending strings and not variables

'MxRelease' + index  is a string and not the variable your declared previously.

To Do something similar you would have to create an object that way

```
TEMPLATe = 
{    tplvar = 
     {
      mxrelease2 : 'your template',
     },
    'MxRelease2' : function(tplvar){return tplvar.mxrelease2;},
}
```

If I am not wrong, it's called dictionnaries (javascript)